# How to condense entries in a DataFrame where 2 columns' value match, while condensing and appending specific data from a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns, the important ones for this question being:

A: A short description in a string: ([A-Za-z]+)

B: A 5-Character identifier: ([A-Za-z0-9]{5})

C: A string that contains a short description, and then a 6-digit ID followed by a 2-digit Sub ID: ([A-Za-z]+=\d{6}\.\d{2} )

Example:

```
      A                B           C
0  Some_Str          AAAAA       A_ID=000001.01
1  Some_Other_Str    BBBBB       B_ID=000002.02
2  Some_Str          AAAAA       A_ID=000001.02
```

I would like the best way to condense the DataFrame so that if two rows have a matching 'A' and 'B' value, they are combined.  I am aware of functions like group_by and agg for pandas.DataFrames, however, while condensing I would also like to append the two digit sub ID from 'C' to the remaining entry for that combination, as well as count/include the number of occurrences, if possible.  The example output for this DataFrame that I would hope to attain is (or something similar):

```
       A                 B             C
0   Some_Str           AAAAA     A_ID=00001.01.02 (2)
1   Some_Other_Str     BBBBB     B_ID=00002.02
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using a: `DataFrame.groupby().agg()`
method with a custom `agg()` function.  The function parses the entry in Column C for the two digit SubID, appends it to the first entry, and then returns only the first combined SubID entry.